# List of authors of articles in a view

Tags: views

I am trying to create a page which lists the users who are an author of a node type of article.

I figured I would approach it by creating a view based upon article. So the view started out listing all articles. Then I set up a relationship to users where the user is the author of the article, and in the fields, I just have it output the author's name (user name).

Now I have a list of all of the authors, but it repeats. So you see John Smith a hundred times, if he wrote 100 articles.

How do you make it so that John Smith only shows up once? If I could edit the mysql, I would just use group by uid (so the user only shows once), but in drupal views, it will list that author as a heading for a group, and then list all the articles he was in (so in my setup, it would show his name followed by a listing of his name many times).

This is in Drupal 7

Comment: 0.25 bitcoins to whoever can gets me the best usable answer in the next 2 days. Just put your address in the comment to your answer.

Comment: this site is running on "points" ;-) If you ever need more or better answers try the "bounty"

Answer (score 2):

you are almost there. Just set "Use aggregation" to yes. Also, make sure there is not other field in "sort criteria".